# How to interpret these gravitational lensing data?

Tags: experimental-physics, astronomy, gravitational-lensing

[The data](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/castles/)

I am trying to understand this gravitational lensing data in the link above. However, unfortunately I don't have an extensive knowledge in physics. Could someone please tell me what each of the following labels mean

$z_s$, $z_l$  $RA (J2000)$, $Dec (J2000)$, $E(B-V)$, $ms (mag)$, $ml (mag)$, $FGHz (mJy)$, $N_im$  $size (")$  dt (days) and   $sigma (km/s)$.

Also, how can I calculate the gravitational lensing angle from the data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Did you notice the caption of the table?

[image: Caption of the tablen]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that. Just one question, How to calculate the lensing angle from the table

Comment: I don't know if it is possible or not. From the source and lens redshifts you can clearly calculate their distances using the Hubble's law. But I also don't know how to extract the geometrical parameters.